# Listing All Possible 'Shortest' Paths

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a combinatorial problem which can be treated as a network search problem. In order to visualize and use already implemented functions, I decided to use networkx package (I actually do not have enough time to implement it in other way).

My problem is unfortunately quite complex. But, I will try to ease the understanding by explaining even the simplest things. In general, I need to find out the combinations to reach the nodes where the tree is ending.

The figure below shows a trivial example:

[image]

---

In this case, `B`, `D`, `F`, `H` are terminal nodes, whereas starting point is denoted with `O`. So, a path combination could be:

```
OAB
OCD
OED
OEF
OH
OGH
```

However, I actually search for the 'shortest' or 'most favorable' paths to reach the terminal nodes. The diagram (or the edges) does not give any information about the 'cost' of the path. The cost evaluation will be done according to the results of the combinations found. Evaluating the 'actual' costs of the combinations found is computationally very expensive. Although the diagram does not yield much information, one thing is clear: in order to reach `H`, `OH` is at any time a better choice than `OGH`. So, the combination `OGH` can be eliminated from the possible combinations list. It is essentially like the distance metric.

One more point, in fact, `D` and `F` correspond to equivalent points (they are distinct nodes but have the same meaning for my application). Such an information can however only be gained if two nodes

```
- see each other
- see exactly the same nodes
```

If looked at the figure carefully, it can also be recognized that `C` and `E` are equivalent nodes. So, to state it more specifically: the combinations of `OCD` and `OED` are actually the same. Once `OCD` is added to combination-list, there is not any need to add `OED`. It can also be seen from the figure, as D and F are the same, once `OCD` is added to the list, there is not any need to add `OCF`.

To sum up, the solution in this case would be:

```
OAB
anyone of OCD, OED, OCF, OEF
OH
```

To sketch that digram, I followed the tutorials of networkx and then created the code below:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = [('O', 'A'), ('O', 'C'),  ('O', 'E'),  ('O', 'G'),  ('O', 'H'),  
         ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'O'),
         ('B', 'A'),
         ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F'), ('C', 'O'),
         ('D', 'E'), ('D', 'C'), ('D', 'F'),  
         ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('E', 'O'),
         ('F', 'C'), ('F', 'D'), ('F', 'E'),
         ('G', 'H'), ('G', 'O'), 
         ('H', 'G'), ('H', 'O')]

G=nx.DiGraph()
for edge in graph:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

So, my question is to list up such sequences using any toolbox, but preferably networkx. The first step to do is probably simplifying (or reducing) the graph before creating a Graph object. Once the simplified graph is obtained, using `nx.all_simple_path` command, all the alternative paths can be listed. I need your help in doing such a graph reduction.

My graphs are not deep, they are generally about the same size as given in the example.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: I tried BFS and DFS. But I can only get one result. Not all the possible combinations.

Comment: You write: "in order to reach H, OH is at any time a better choice than 'OGH'". Why?

Comment: @JohnB I assume because ``OGH`` is a superset of ``OH``, but that presumes all edge costs are equal. Otherwise there is no way to 'reduce redundancy' without actually calculating the costs.

Comment: @JohnB using pathlength as a metric, it is one hop from `OH` compared to two hops for `OGH` (if I understood OP correctly)

Comment: Yes, but if I know the metric, why not simply search for the shortest path, then? Finding only one (the shortest) path will be probably much faster (O(n^2)) than finding all of them and afterwards removing some (exponential time, in the worst case, I guess).

Comment: The "actual problem" image isn't shown.

Comment: I have just fixed it. I am just reading your comments...

Comment: @JohnB it is actually an euclidean distance metric. Therefore...

Comment: Can you again explain why you do not simply search for the shortest path?

Comment: For the "actual problem", the solution "OG" would also be possible (an alternative to "OH"), right? Given that "H" and "G" are equivalent by your definition.

Comment: Is the starting point always labelled "O"?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe `G` is not a final node. If it would be, then your it would be a solution

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, yes, O is always a starting point

Comment: Why is `H` a final node but not `G` (in your second example, mind you)?

Comment: @JohnB because, my cost is not exactly the distance. There are other parameters specifying my cost. Therefore, I evaluate it inside a different and a very complicated script

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, The end nodes are always the same. They do not change. They are found from a separately. I may not have drawn the figure according to the order (or rank) of the nodes...

Comment: Sorry, I really do not get it. Approach: Search for equivalent nodes in your graph and reduce the graph to a simpler one by removing nodes or edges, to account for the fact that you consider some nodes equivalent to each other. Then do breadth-first to find all cycle-free paths. But you won't find an algorithm taking into account that nodes are equivalent without specifying which nodes these are.

Comment: @JohnB, probably you are right. The best way is to do the simplification before creating such a graph. After the simplified graph is generated, then using the `nx.all_simple_paths` all of the possible solutions can be obtained...

Comment: @JohnB I will edit my questions and seek for an answer, that simplifies the graph for the second type of problem formulation. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read the complete module handbook and I tried different search algorithms, but I couldn't find an existing implementation, or any workaround for such a specific case.

So, with the advice gained from the comments, I wrote my own simplifier and removed all of the 'redundant' nodes before creating the graph. I did it just by transforming the lists in sets and then by comparing whether they are identical. Afterwards, I created the graph and listed up all the solutions using `nx.all_simple_paths` command. Once I got the paths, this time I searched for whether there are any paths (like `OGH`) when whose letter before the last, i.e. index [-2], is removed the resulting path (`OH`) is also in the list of `nx.all_simple_paths`. If yes, then I removed that solution out.

The script I coded is quite unorganized, and doesn't involve special techniques. Therefore, I have chosen to write the solution methodology.